# Why don't all my app installations show in Parse.com for iOS?

Tags: ios, parsing, analytics, dashboard

I have followed the Parse.com tutorial on installing code to track installs and analytics. However, the dashboard does not show all of my app installs.

For example, i know that i have about 700 installs from looking at the iTunes Connect sales data, but only half of those show in Parse.

I've searched Stackoverflow and watched a number of the Parse developer day videos but a reason for this is not mentioned. Any help with this would be amazing.

thanks for your time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons why this might be happening:

1. iTunes connect is tracking all installs, but some of those might be duplicates, meaning a person is downloading the app for a second time to the same device. Parse is not counting new installs on a device that has already been registered.
2. Some of your downloads happened before you installed Parse analytics and they haven't opened the app since then. People may have downloaded a new version automatically (iOS 7 and 8 do this) but not opened the version with the analytics code - hence they count on iTunes Connect but not on Parse.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! Much appreciated, this definitely clears things up. I was curious as to whether these installs we're maybe tied to subscribing to push notifications. - for example, if someone excludes themselves from recievinig the notifications, does this mean they data also doesnt show in the dashboard. thanks