# Not all app downloads from iTunes are registering as app installs in parse.com

Tags: ios, parse-platform, download, installation

I have an app that was just updated and now includes the Parse.com SDK.

Over the last week I've had 100 thousand upgrades of this parse-utilizing version of the app (that may or may not have been launched yet) and 50 thousand "free" first time downloads.

That's anywhere from 50 to 150 thousand downloads in total.

But my Parse.com app only shows 15 thousand installs.

How can this be? How can this many downloads result in so few installs?

Do some installs not get counted? Is there a "failed" install stat anywhere? The app is big enough that wi-fi is needed to download it, so the user is obviously connected when the download occurs.

Thoughts?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201584/why-dont-all-my-app-installations-show-in-parse-com-for-ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201584/why-dont-all-my-app-installations-show-in-parse-com-for-ios)

Comment: Thanks, Adrianokw, but I've seen that thread. The author was dealing with only 700 downloads and the "double downloads by one user" answer seemed satisfactory to them. But I've had well over 50,000 apple-reported first time downloads, on top of 100,000 updates in the past week alone. Yet I only see 15,000 installs, or 10% of the downloads. There is no way people are downloading it 10 times to their devices. There must be some other explanation for the 3x - 10x discrepancy between Apple's reports and my Parse database. Do Parse.com installs ever fail? And if so, is that data viewable?

Comment: You didn't comment on this part "people may have downloaded a new version automatically (iOS 7 and 8 do this) but not opened the version with the analytics code - hence they count on iTunes Connect but not on Parse". Can't this be the case, people downloaded or updated your app but never opened it?

Comment: Thanks again.  In the text above I detail that 100k people updated the app. Many could be automatic, and thus unopened.

Separate from this were 50k first time downloads, according to Apple, all on the same day.

There's no way that only 15k installations came from 50k first time downloads and 100k updates. No matter how you slice it, there's no way that only 1 in 10 people launched the app after downloading it.

Thus, what explains the discrepancy between Apple and Parse? The gap is far too wide and the intentional downloads are far too great to be explained by unnoticed auto-downloads.